# Using custom debug keystore for intellij-idea community android does not work

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When trying to use a custom debug keystore for the IDE run process, it always fails with:

```
Android Packager: [android] java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

This keystore works fine when I build with Maven. Anyone have any ideas what is wrong? Perhaps I need to supply the password somewhere?

EDIT: 
For the record, when you enter in a new key name, the IDE will automatically create a new key with the password "android". However, is there any way to provide a debug key with your own password?

Intellij IDEA 12.1.2 Community

Answer (score 1):

Just a FYI, intellij 12 did not allow you to use a custom password. THe password and alias always need to match the default android keystore.